# Sorted list template implemented using doubly linked list

Tags: c++, c++11, doubly-linked-list, sortedcollection

I am working on this program where I have to write a sorted list template implemented using doubly linked list. The SortedList.cpp is given to me, which contains the test bed main. I should implement the template in SortedList.h file.

The template has a Insert, Delete and Print Function, a default constructor and the Big 3. Copy the content of the Print function in your own template:

```
// Implementation of Print function
int i = 1;
Node * p = list;
while ( p != NULL )
{
    cout << "Node " << i << ": " << p->data << endl;
    p = p->next;
    i++;
}
```

I did write SortedList.h, but when I compare my output with the correct output, I find that it doesn't match.

Here is SortedList.h:

```
// SortedList.h list template implemented using doubly linked list.
#ifndef SORTEDLIST_H_
#define SORTEDLIST_H_
# include <iostream>
using namespace std;
// struct defining the node of the linked list
template <typename T>
struct Node {
    T data;
    Node<T> *next, *pre;
};
// class which defines the linked list
template <typename T>
class SortedList {
private:
    Node<T> *head;
public:
    // default constructor
    SortedList<T>()
    {
        head = NULL;
    }
    // fucntion Insert to insert the node at the end of the list
    void Insert(T n)
    {
        Node<T> *newNode = new Node<T>;
        newNode->data = n;
        newNode->next = NULL;
        newNode->pre = NULL;
        if (head == NULL)
        {
            head = newNode;
        }
        else if (head->data > n)
        {
            Node<T>* temp = head;
            head = newNode;
            newNode->next = temp;
            temp->pre = head;
        }
        else {
            Node<T> *temp = head;
            Node<T> *prev = NULL;
            bool inserted = false;
            while (temp != NULL)
            {
                if (temp->data > n)
                {
                    //Node* _temp = temp;
                    newNode->pre = temp->pre;
                    newNode->next = temp;
                    temp->pre = newNode;
                    if (newNode->pre != NULL)
                    {
                        newNode->pre->next = newNode;
                    }
                    inserted = true;
                    break;
                }
                prev = temp;
                temp = temp->next;
            }
            if (!inserted)
            {
                newNode->pre = prev;
                prev->next = newNode;
            }
        }
    }
    // function to delete the node with the data n
    void Delete(T n)
    {
        if (head == NULL)
        {
            return;
        }
        else {
            if (head->data == n)
            {
                Node<T> *temp = head;
                head = head->next;
                if (head != NULL)
                    head->pre = NULL;
                delete(temp);
            }
            else {
                Node<T> *temp = head->next;
                while (temp != NULL)
                {
                    if (temp->data == n)
                    {
                        {
                            temp->pre->next = temp->next;
                            if (temp->next != NULL)
                                temp->next->pre = temp->pre;
                        }
                        Node<T>* toDelete = temp;
                        temp = temp->pre;
                        if (toDelete != NULL)
                            delete(toDelete);
                    }
                    temp = temp->next;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    // function to print the list
    void Print()
    {
        if (head == NULL)
            cout << "\n Empty list ";
        else
        {
            int i = 1;
            cout << "\n List " << endl;
            Node<T> **temp = &head;
            while ((*temp) != NULL)
            {
                cout << " Node " << i << ":" << (*temp)->data << endl;
                temp = &((*temp)->next);
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
};
#endif /* SORTEDLIST_H_ */
// End of Sorted.h
```

the Output I get:

```
   1: 
   2:  List 
   3:  Node 1: 
   4:  Node 2: 
   5:  Node 3: 
   6:  Node 4: 
   7:  Node 5: 
   8:  Node 6: 
   9:  Node 7: 
  10:  Node 8: 
  11:  Node 9: 
  12:  Node 10:!
  13:  Node 11:a
  14:  Node 12:a
  15:  Node 13:e
  16:  Node 14:e
  17:  Node 15:e
  18:  Node 16:g
  19:  Node 17:g
  20:  Node 18:h
  21:  Node 19:h
  22:  Node 20:i
  23:  Node 21:i
  24:  Node 22:i
  25:  Node 23:i
  26:  Node 24:l
  27:  Node 25:n
  28:  Node 26:n
  29:  Node 27:o
  30:  Node 28:r
  31:  Node 29:r
  32:  Node 30:r
  33:  Node 31:s
  34:  Node 32:s
  35:  Node 33:s
  36:  Node 34:s
  37:  Node 35:s
  38:  Node 36:t
  39:  Node 37:t
  40:  Node 38:t
  41:  Node 39:t
  42:  Node 40:t
  43:  Node 41:t
  44:  Node 42:v
  45:  Node 43:v
  46:  Node 44:y
  47:  Node 45:y
  48: Which one do you want to delete?
  49: Which one do you want to delete?
  50: Which one do you want to delete?
  51: Which one do you want to delete?
  52: Which one do you want to delete?
  53: Which one do you want to delete?
  54: 
  55:  List 
  56:  Node 1: 
  57:  Node 2: 
  58:  Node 3: 
  59:  Node 4: 
  60:  Node 5: 
  61:  Node 6: 
  62:  Node 7: 
  63:  Node 8: 
  64:  Node 9: 
  65:  Node 10:!
  66:  Node 11:e
  67:  Node 12:e
  68:  Node 13:e
  69:  Node 14:g
  70:  Node 15:g
  71:  Node 16:h
  72:  Node 17:h
  73:  Node 18:l
  74:  Node 19:n
  75:  Node 20:n
  76:  Node 21:o
  77:  Node 22:r
  78:  Node 23:r
  79:  Node 24:r
  80:  Node 25:s
  81:  Node 26:s
  82:  Node 27:s
  83:  Node 28:s
  84:  Node 29:s
  85:  Node 30:t
  86:  Node 31:t
  87:  Node 32:t
  88:  Node 33:t
  89:  Node 34:t
  90:  Node 35:t
  91:  Node 36:v
  92:  Node 37:v
  93:  Node 38:y
  94:  Node 39:y
  95: 
  96:  List 
  97:  Node 1:3.14
```

Here is the correct output I should get:

```
1: Node 1:  
   2: Node 2: !
   3: Node 3: a
   4: Node 4: e
   5: Node 5: g
   6: Node 6: h
   7: Node 7: i
   8: Node 8: l
   9: Node 9: n
  10: Node 10: o
  11: Node 11: r
  12: Node 12: s
  13: Node 13: t
  14: Node 14: v
  15: Node 15: y
  16: Which one do you want to delete?
  17: Which one do you want to delete?
  18: Which one do you want to delete?
  19: Which one do you want to delete?
  20: Which one do you want to delete?
  21: Which one do you want to delete?
  22: Node 1:  
  23: Node 2: !
  24: Node 3: e
  25: Node 4: g
  26: Node 5: h
  27: Node 6: l
  28: Node 7: n
  29: Node 8: o
  30: Node 9: r
  31: Node 10: s
  32: Node 11: t
  33: Node 12: v
  34: Node 13: y
  35: Node 1: 3.14
```

Would anyone be able to tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thank you

Comment: Big 3 is now big 5 FYI.

Comment: Hi, your `insert` and `delete` methods seems ok. Your print method is also ok for me but why are you using pointer to pointer unnecessarily? Can you provide me the code how are you calling method `insert` and `delete`?

Answer (score 0):

The `Delete` function has a strange asymmetry: if the element to be removed is the first one, the function only removes that single element; otherwise it removes all the occurrences of the element.

For example:

```
SortedList<char> l;

l.Insert('z');
l.Insert('z');
l.Insert('a');
l.Insert('a');
l.Insert('x');
l.Insert('x');
// l == {'a','a', 'x', 'x', 'z', 'z'}
```

now:

```
l.Delete('z');
// l = {'a','a', 'x', 'x'}
```

all the occurrences of `'z'` are gone.

While:

```
l.Delete('a');
// l = {'a', 'x', 'x'}
```

just removes one element.

This explains the different results you get.

You should change:

```
if (head->data == n)
{
  Node<T> *temp = head;
  head = head->next;
  if (head != NULL)
    head->pre = NULL;
  delete(temp);
}
```

to handle multiple deletions.